# Google Spreadsheet ImportXML error #NA not received any data as a result of XPath queries

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

I have a problem with scraping one website - [motoallegro](http://allegro.pl/samochody-149)

I want to get title of all ads in this [page](http://allegro.pl/samochody-149?order=qd&string=Primera%20GT&search_scope=automotive&department=automotive)

So I set formula in google spreadsheet:

```
=ImportXML("http://allegro.pl/samochody-149?order=qd&string=Primera+GT&search_scope=automotive&department=automotive";"//header/h2/a/span")
```

This formula always return #NA error: not received any data as a result of XPath queries

But if I try to get other data from the same page, for example H1 text:

```
=ImportXML("http://allegro.pl/samochody-149?order=qd&string=Primera+GT&search_scope=automotive&department=automotive";"//h1/span")
```

The result is correct: "Primera GT"

I want to add, that xPath rule - //header/h2/a/span IS CORRECT. I tested it on few firefox xPath plugins.

Any ideas, why google spreadsheet formula ImportXML with correct xPath rule not return correct data?

Answer (score 2):

Google seems to strip non-HTML4-tags like `<header/>` and `<section/>`. You could use `<div id="listing">...</div>` for accessing only the headlines you need.

Try this XPath expression:

```
//div[@id='listing']//h2/a/span
```

Comment: Maybe you're right - Google seems to strip non-HTML4-tag. Your expression is CORRECT. THANKS ;)